# golang pass in args (a slice of strings) as "args ... interface{}"

Tags: go

**Here is my code:**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
)

func main() {
    table := "some table"

    args := []interface{}{"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"}

    _, err := db.Exec( "INSERT INTO" + table + "VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?)", args)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
}
```

I want to pass in the args but cannot format them as `"args ...interface{}"`

**Current output is:**

`sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `...` operator to expand the args slice.

Comment: thats not working, i still get the same error:
sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice

Comment: Please, post a Minimal, Verifiable Example so we can help you.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/79yNm_1Sa1

since the example works fine and only db.Exec is causing the issue i have decided to use a different approach, thanks for your time and effort :)

Comment: @Andy Schweig solved the problem. The example you provided doesn't do what you think, the args you pass to the insert function is seen as only one element because it isn't expanded.

Answer (score 14):

In the `db.Exec` call, use `args...` instead of `args`.